ReadAsStreamAsync memory limit Azure Functions
I am trying to download a very large dataset from ICO, This is the link https://ico.org.uk/about-the-ico/what-we-do/register-of-fee-payers/download-the-register/
public async Task<Stream> DownloadLatestDataset()
{
    var path = $"media/about-the-ico/data-sets/register-of-data-controllers/register-of-data-controllers_{DateTime.Today:yyyy-MM-dd}.zip";
    var response = await client.GetAsync(path);

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        throw new HttpRequestException($"Failed to download file: {response.StatusCode}");
    }

    var contentType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType?.MediaType;

    if (contentType == "text/html")
    {
        throw new DatasetException();
    }
    
    var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    return stream;
}

It works great locally, but when I try to run in azure functions it times out on the ReadAsStreamAsync. I have tried increasing to dedicated production plan with no success / difference.
Does anyone know of any techniques I can use to download the zip file? I then turn it directly into a csv after this. I have also tried the likes of ADF but file is too big to be brought in. File size of zip folder is 65mb (one single csv file).
My only thought process I can try now is exploring options outside of az functions, maybe az app service under web api or through azure vm? Trying to keep costs low so this is important too.
Cheers
Edit
I have now tried adding a buffer
public async Task<Stream> DownloadLatestDataset()
{
    var path = $"media/about-the-ico/data-sets/register-of-data-controllers/register-of-data-controllers_{DateTime.Today:yyyy-MM-dd}.zip";
    var response = await client.GetAsync(path);

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        throw new HttpRequestException($"Failed to download file: {response.StatusCode}");
    }

    var contentType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType?.MediaType;

    if (contentType == "text/html")
    {
        throw new DatasetException();
    }

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        var buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        long totalBytesRead = 0;
        long totalBytes = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength ?? -1;

        while ((bytesRead = await contentStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            await memoryStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

            if (totalBytes > 0)
            {
                var progress = (int)((double)totalBytesRead / totalBytes * 100);
                Console.WriteLine($"Downloading... {progress}%");
            }
        }
    }

    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    return memoryStream;
}

Works fine locally but in az function when gets to 90% it stops and get this error

Further edit
I have tried this in azure functions premium and it seems to work. But this is not feasible as this is a pre revenue project. If there are any reccomendations / ideas to run this for low cost or free please still help out.
Context
I have now eddited to show the context of how this is used, I am searching for a row in the csv to get more details.
public async Task<OrganisationRegistration?> GetRegistration(string checkNumber)
{
    var cacheKey = "RegistrationData";
    
    if(!cache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out IEnumerable<OrganisationRegistration>? registrations))
    {
        registrations = await GetDeserializedCsvData();
        cache.Set(cacheKey, registrations);
    }

    return registrations?.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RegistrationNumber == checkNumber);
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<OrganisationRegistration>> GetDeserializedCsvData()
{
    var csvFileName = $"register-of-data-controllers_{DateTime.Today:yyyy-MM-dd}.csv";
    using var zipStream = await DownloadLatestDataset();
    using var csvStream = await ZipHelper.ExtractCsvFromZipAsync(zipStream, csvFileName);
    using var reader = new StreamReader(csvStream);
    using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvConfiguration(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        HasHeaderRecord = true,
        Delimiter = ",",
        IgnoreBlankLines = true,
        TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim,
    });

    return csv.GetRecords<OrganisationRegistration>().ToList();
}

And my zip helper
using System.IO.Compression;

public static class ZipHelper
{
    public static async Task<Stream> ExtractCsvFromZipAsync(Stream zipStream, string csvFileName)
    {
        using var archive = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read);
        var entry = archive.GetEntry(csvFileName) ?? throw new FileNotFoundException("CSV file not found in the zip archive.");
        var outputStream = new MemoryStream();

        using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
        {
            await entryStream.CopyToAsync(outputStream);
        }

        outputStream.Position = 0;
        return outputStream;
    }
}



"works locally" but "times out [in Azure]" - does downloading locally take longer than the Azure function timeout? If so, increase the function timeout. 2. If it's a large file, you'll probably need to buffer into a stream; have you seen this question? Timed out when trying to download a file through HttpClient


@MetroSmurf it doesn't take that long locally at all.... I think it might be memory issue but will take a look at this thanks :)

@MetroSmurf I have edited question please see update :)

Why in the first version are you serializing the stream in a json object and then logging it? That seems very strange and it could be the very issue.

@Alberto hi sorry ignore this it was just to try and debug what is going on. I will edit original code. I can confirm it still does not work without this bit.

You need to tell us what you're doing with the Stream... In other words, what's the code that is calling your DownloadLatestDataset() method? Does it really need a MemoryStream - because that's causing you to hold the whole thing in memory, which might be the issue. Might be best to share more of the code.

Sure @AndrewB I have eddited to show context, good point I havn't looked into a way of finding a row without reading whole thing.... I will look into this unless you have ideas of a best practice?

Great. Next question: the ZipHelper library. What options do you have with that? Can you share what that is too?

Hey sure @AndrewB, sure have added my zip helper, got a feeling we need some new methods in here!

OK I see. Yes, you'll have to rethink this. Some comments: 1: You can't get around reading the whole stream into memory at once, because that's what the ZipArchive needs. You'll need that amount of RAM. 2: The buffering isn't helping at all; you still end up with the same amount in memory, so it's just adding complexity. 3: It looks like you do this operation every time someone calls GetRegistration, but a better approach would be to have a one-time operation to read and parse the Zip into a CSV blob (perhaps a timer trigger function) and then just read the parsed CSV each time.

@AndrewB, sure sounds good, especially as only updated daily and memory cache can only last 1 hour az function . I was going to explore running this as a worker on azure vm I think it might use less memory for cheaper but will have to investigate, otherwise functions premium could be only way!! Or azure vm + worker to unzip + upload to azure as csv then the az function can do the rest

You may want to review the service limits for Azure functions. In that table there is a row for "Max memory (GB per instance)". Compare the values in that table against the size of your zip file. From there you can decide if Azure functions makes sense from a cost perspective.
